# Unable to boot 12.04 due to segmentation fault

Tags: dual-boot, boot-failure, segmentation-fault

I am having 12.04 LTS installation alongside Windows 7. When I boot Ubuntu, it fails to boot into login screen instead it gives the following error:

```
udevd[121]: 'sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sda2' [284] terminated by signal 11 (segmentation fault)

Busybox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs)
```

*Can any one help me out on what to do next?*

I would like to point out that my Ubuntu was working fine and this error started popping up suddenly, although the segmentation fault in `/dev/sda2` error was coming from a long time due to that I just could not mount that drive. By the way `/dev/sda2` contains `C:` drive of Windows.

Comment: any help from anyone?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how can I recover my system from `(initramfs)` ? I can't get my Ubuntu started.

Answer (score 0):

try  this one : use "xinit" command or "resume",it might help. after that do a fsck (file system check).

Comment: If an fsck needed to be done, it should have been done before `xinit`.